# Server doesn't receive audio file url although the response is succes

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avfoundation, alamofire

So I'm trying to upload to the server my audio file.

From the server I need to fulfil this things :

```
messages/create -> route
type: POST
mandatory:
message_token  // message_token must be generated unique
message  // type FILE => message_token + message_id + owner_id + .amr
duration // example: 4000, means 4 sec
general: user_token ,source, version 

response if success:
{
status: "success",
message: "Conversation has been successfully created!",
```

In my code, I m using Alamofire for http requests.

```
    func createMessage() {
    let url = URL(string: Helper.apiUrl + "messages/create")
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multiplePartFormData) in
        let appVersion = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleShortVersionString"]
        let duration = 4000

        var multiplePartFormData: Dictionary<String, Any> = ["message_token": self.curentFileName ?? 0,
                                                  "duration": duration,
                                                  "user_token" : userDefaults.value(forKey: "user_token") as! String,
                                                  "source":"ios",
                                                  "version":"\(String(describing: appVersion!))"]




        do {
           let soundfile = try Data.init(contentsOf: self.soundFileURL)
            multiplePartFormData["message"] = soundfile
        } catch {

        }
    }, usingThreshold: UInt64(), to: url!, method: .post, headers: nil) { (result) in
        print(result)
        switch result {
        case .success:
            print("succes")
        case .failure:
            print("fail")
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is on the server I'm not receiving anything and what's frustrating is that the response is succes ...

> Permision granted
>   writing to soundfile url: 'file:///66974D10D61/data/Containers/Data/Application/494935E8-1E8D-48D6-8577-84E84B3D97B0/Documents/Optional(2018030718503271072).37.m4a'
>
> success(request: 2018-03-07 18:50:34.670385+0200 VoiceMe[36784:1559418] CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds.  Error=-25300,

```
 query={
    atyp = http;
    class = inet;
    "m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
    ptcl = http;
    "r_Attributes" = 1;
    sdmn = "v.site.com";
    srvr = "v.site.com";
    sync = syna;
}
```

> $ curl -v \   -X POST \   -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data;
>   boundary=alamofire.boundary.c0201af3574a47dd" \   -H "Accept-Language:
>   en;q=1.0" \   -H "User-Agent: VoiceMe/1.0 (; build:1; iOS 11.2.0)
>   Alamofire/4.6.0" \    -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0, compress;q=0.5" \
>     "http://blabla/pi/v1/messages/create", streamingFromDisk: true,
>   streamFileURL:
>   Optional(file:///Users/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E65D9E9F-7553-4C3F-A7D9D61/data/Containers/Data/Application/494935E8-1E8D-48D6-8577-84E84B3D97B0/tmp/org.alamofire.manager/multipart.form.data/9B16CF74-A6BC-4AC7-89E8-68633E5DB91E))
>
> succes

Anyone faced this issue? or have any idea? Appreciate.